# Fetching rows changed or added last day without time field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want query a table to find the changed rows last day. But there is no explicit `time filed`  in column name. Is there any way I can access these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a field indicating when a record was changed there is no way to determine when a record was changed, therefore it is unfortunately impossible for you to query the records changed yesterday.